# Magento 2: How to replace minicart icon

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shopping-cart, mini-cart

How can I replace the minicart icon when using a custom theme?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this in your .css:

```
.minicart-wrapper a.action.showcart::before {
    content: "*whatever content you want, for example Font Awesome*";
}
```

You can also use a `background-image`.

Here's how to include CSS in your theme: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your theme. If this is a standard theme(luma), then you need to change the styles in the .css file. For the selector `.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before`.

Comment: where can I find those css class? please explain eleborately

Comment: please tell in which css file I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

::First let me clear that you can't edit magento core themes directly from /app/design/magento!!!::

::If you want to change it your self then, you've to create your own one and make changes as required!!::

::Now let's go to the point!::

::first => `Create custom.css file at /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/`::

::second => `create default.xml file at /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/`::

::Now put the file contents like below::

::CSS::

::

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{
    
    content:url('../images/minicart.jpg')!important;
    
    zoom:1.5%;
    }
```

::

::XML::

```
<head>
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

//make sure to copy the default structure for xml file.

//I have not pasted that here because i am a noob to stackexchange!!

:::Last Step :::

```
move your new minicart image to the /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/images/minicart.img extension
```

::Finally run below commands::

::Make sure to remove /pub/static/frontend::

::`bin/magento setup:upgrade`::

::`bin/magento setup:di:compile`::

::`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`::

::`bin/magento indexer:reindex`::

::`bin/magento cache:flush`::

::`chmod -R 777 ../magento root directory name`::

::Thank You::