# Smartwave porto cart icon need to change

Tags: magento2, php

I have tried to change the code in _mincart_lesss but cart is not changed in website.Any one can help me on this?

[image]

Comment: You can contact PORTO theme support. They will help you.

Comment: I have tried to change the cart using in background url in app/design/frontend/Smartwave_Access/porto/web/css/custom.css file [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBlFc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBlFc.png) ANd i have tried to change the variable of the cart in app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/css/source/variable_less [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rgdk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rgdk.png) This both case not working for me.Do you have any suggestion on this.

Comment: not sure but I think you can modify it from porto settings panel

Comment: Should i run the below commend after done the changes,i just upload the modified file in FTP account and clear cache.Need a suggestion on this php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your .css:

.minicart-wrapper a.action.showcart::before {
    content: "*whatever content you want, for example Font Awesome*";
}
You can also use a background-image.

Here's how to include CSS in your theme: **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html**

And more useful link :-

**[Magento 2: How to replace minicart icon](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227791/magento-2-how-to-replace-minicart-icon)**

Hope this help you

Thanks...